# Unable to open popup when using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Login Page and Registration page.
I Used  a "Forgot Password" link.
If the user clicks "Forgot password", a new popup should open.
I am using Bootstrap .When I click "Forgot Password" it doesn't open the pop up. i also tried a different method, it's not working.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Daily UI - Day 1 Sign In</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700|Lato:400,100,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Custom Stylesheet -->

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Modal.css"/>

        
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="container">
       
            <header>        
            </header>
            <section>               
                <div id="container_demo">
                   
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                    <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="login" class="animate form">
                          
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername or mymail@mail.com"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" id="myBtn" value="Login In" /> 
                                        <!-- The Modal -->

                                </p>    
                         
                              
                            
                               <p class="change_link">
                                 <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Forgot my password</a>
                                   
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                           
                               </div>   
                               
                               
                               
                               <div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>modal popup</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                               
                               
                        
                        <div id="register" class="animate form">
                             
                                <h1> Sign up </h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
                                    <input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e" > Your email</label>
                                    <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
                                    <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                                </p>
                                <p class="signin button"> 
                                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                                </p>
                            
                                <p class="change_link"> 
                                    
                                    
                                    <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
                                </p>
                           
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>          
                </div>  
</body>
```

When I click Forgot password,  nothing shows up. Please help me ?
Where am I making a mistake?
How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713414/bootstrap-modal-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jQuery library before bootstrap

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Note:-

Yout HTML code seems very messy (multiple unclosed element along with misplaced element too,please correct them)

Comment: sure i will check

Comment: working  thank you

Comment: @sripriya  glad to help you:):)

Comment: @Anant Begging for upvotes is frowned upon: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63439

Comment: @Rizier123  sorry i don't knew that. i will promise  that today onward i am not going to do that. deep apology from my side

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the jQuery script above the Bootstrap one

Comment: thank you sir @Jose Manuel Lucas